# How to setup Atom editor to use only the react-native-community eslint-config?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, atom-editor

I want to setup Atom editor to use only the `@react-native-community/eslint-config`.I want Atom to autoformat my files whenever I save a file. I have created a new React Native project using `react-native init`. What are the packages and files I need to add to use this?

Following the steps mentioned in the answers to other questions leads to many confilcting rules which does not autoformat when saving and creates a lot of warnings. For example, `Strings must use singlequote (quotes)` and `Replace '' with "" (prettier/prettier)` are both shown.

Answer (score 0):

Install these packages

```
yarn add -D eslint-config-prettier eslint-plugin-prettier prettier
```

Also add corresponding config in .eslintrc.js

```
{
  extends: ['@react-native-community', "plugin:prettier/recommended"],
}
```